# Caml query for lookupmulti field equal only one value

Tags: linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lookup, caml

I want to filter a Sharepoint list with a caml query for lookupmulti field but i want to filter items which has only one value. For example,

ID LookupMultiField

1 - Value1,Value2,Value11

2 - Value1

3 - Value2,Value3,Value4

When I use Eq statetement for only value "Value1" in my query result is items with ID 1 and 2. But i only want to get item with ID 2. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this directly in CAML on your LookupMultiField.

The easiest way is probably to retrieve all items with Value1, then do additional filtering within your code.

Another approach would be to copy your LookupMultiField to a text field (for example via a workflow), and do the filtering on that text field.

If you only have few values, you could also try to negate your filtering condition (filed NEQ Value2 and NEQ value3 and...).

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator "contains" like:

```
<Where>
    <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name="LookupMultiField" LookupId="True"/>
        <Value Type="Text">1</Value>
    </Contains>
</Where>
```

But you should know ID filter element